# VBA - How to Autofill all the way to the bottom until the last B cell with data

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded a macro and I tried to autofill column C with the COUNTIF function all the way down until B column has their last cell value. It doesn't work with new data so I tried to edit the macro and replace it with Range("D2:D") but that doesn't work.

```
Sub COUNTIF()
'
' COUNTIF Macro
'

'
    Range("D2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(C[-3],RC[-3])>1"
    Range("D2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D")
End Sub
```

Comment: [Find the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) and use that in your range reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to find the last cell. Also avoid using select as it slows down your code.

```
Sub COUNTIF()

Dim LastRowB As Long
LastRowB = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("D2").FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(C[-3],RC[-3])>1"
Range("D2: " & "D" & LastRowB).FillDown

End Sub
```

Now change your `"=COUNTIF(C[-3],RC[-3])>1"` formula to whatever it is you really want to fill down.